# Widechar to Bytes using bits pattern?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

If the number of bytes in UTF-8 encoded wide char is known, would it be possible get bytes using the following method?

**For example:**

Wide character `¿` code `191` to bytes gives `-62` and `-65`

I've tried to fit the 8 bits in `191` into the slots but didn't get the same result

```
110[0][0][0][1][0]   10[1][1][1][1][1][1]

      127                   255
```

Comment: What programming language? What's the code that you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't convert to signed bytes. That just confuses matters. So code point 191 yields the byte sequence 194 191

```
Decimal: 194                   191
Binary:  110[0][0][0][1][0]    10[1][1][1][1][1][1]
```

To generate these bytes, you start from the right edge. You get six bits from the 191 and two more from the 194, with an additional three bits leftover, yielding:

```
Binary:  00000[0][0][0]    [1][0][1][1][1][1][1][1]
Decimal: 0                 191
```

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) has a surprisingly good writeup on how this all works.